# Django : Why is my submit interest form not submitted. Did I write my view or template wrongly?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Django : Why is my submit interest form not submitted. Did I write my view or template wrongly?
Based on the view I wrote, I dont even get redirected after I click on submit. And when i return to the home page, i Receive a message from here

`messages.warning(request, 'Something went wrong. Please try again..', extra_tags='wronginterest')`

which is why I believe it is because the form is not valid thats why it is not submitting. but wth why is it not valid?? Thanks

views.py

```
def submit_interest_view(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    blog_post = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
    num_blogpost = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=request.user).count()
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('must_authenticate')
    elif blog_post.author == request.user:
        return HttpResponse('You cannot submit interest to your own post.')
    interest_requests = Interest.objects.filter(interestsender=request.user, interestreceiver=blog_post.author)
    for interest_request in interest_requests:
        if interest_request.is_active:
                    return HttpResponse('You have already submitted your interest to this post.')
    if request.method == 'POST':  # use request.method == 'POST' to submit POST request (like submitting a form)
        form = SubmitInterestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            author = Account.objects.get(email=user.email)  # use get if you aim to get a single object not a queryset
            obj.author = author
            obj.blog_post = blog_post
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your interests have been submitted', extra_tags='submittedinterest')
            context['success_message'] = "Updated"
            if request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("HomeFeed:main")):
                return redirect(reverse("HomeFeed:main"))
            elif request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("HomeFeed:detail", kwargs={'slug': slug })):        
                return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:detail', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
            else:   
                return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:main'))     
            #return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:detail', kwargs={'slug': slug})) # redirect to your post detail but use reverse to pass kwargs not just redirect
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Something went wrong. Please try again..', extra_tags='wronginterest')
    else:
        form = SubmitInterestForm()  #  if request.method isnt POST you still need to define your form so it can be displayed
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/submitinterest.html", {'form': form,'user': user, 'num_blogpost': num_blogpost, 'blog_post': blog_post}) # context dict
```

forms.py

```
HomeFeed: forms.py:
class SubmitInterestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Interest
        fields = ['my_name', 'my_thoughts','short_file',]
```

models.py

```
class Interest(models.Model):
   interestsender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='interestsender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   interestreceiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='interestreceiver', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   timestamp        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   is_active            = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)
   my_name           = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   my_thoughts         = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
   short_file      = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/', null=True, blank=True)

   
  def upload_location(instance, filename):
 #you define this variable called file_path. It belongs to the HomeFeed app, and takes in the parameter of author id, title of blog post with the file name that the author uploads it, and you want to format it 
 file_path = 'HomeFeed/{author_id}/{title}-{filename}'.format(
    author_id=str(instance.author.id),title=str(instance.chief_title), filename=filename)
    #the above will let you insert the strings, you want to take ID of the user who is uploading and converting it into a string, and also the title and file name, converting them into string
 # return file path means where the images is stored, either the local machine/ production environment which will be the name file stored in the content delivery network
 return file_path
 
 class BlogPost(models.Model):
 chief_title                    = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
 body                   = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
 likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_posts', blank=True)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
 date_published             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="date published")
 
 
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True) 
 date_joined                = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
 last_login             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
 is_admin               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_active              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 is_staff               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_superuser           = models.BooleanField(default=False)

 USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
 REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

html:

```
submit_interest.thml


   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    
  <div class="form-group">
   <input class="form-control bg-white form-control-plaintext c" rows="10" type="text" name="my_name" id="my_name" placeholder="Name: {{ request.user.username }}" readonly></input>
  </div>



 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="my_thoughts text-dark">thoughts:</label>
   <textarea  class="form-control" rows="6" type="text" name="my_thoughts" id="my_thoughts" placeholder="My thoughts..." required></textarea >
  </div>


    <label for="short_file " class="text-dark">Brief file (Optional):</label>
    <input type="file"  class="btn btn-md btn-light" name="short_file" id="short_file"> <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-info">Upload</button>-->
   {% if uploaded_file_url %}
    <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>
   {% endif %}

     
   <button class="submit-button btn btn-lg btn-primary mt-3 btn-block col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 " type="submit">Submit Interest</button>

 
  </form>
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'HomeFeed'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_feed_view , name= "main"),
    path('submitinterest/<slug>', submit_interest_view, name= "submitinterest"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out why this is not validating. When the form is not valid, send the form instance back to template via context and try to render the errors. For example:

```
# view

if form.is_valid():
   # ...
else:
   messages.warning(request, 'Something went wrong. Please try again..', extra_tags='wronginterest')
   return render(request, "HomeFeed/submitinterest.html", {'form': form,'user': user, 'num_blogpost': num_blogpost, 'blog_post': blog_post}) # context dict 
    

# template

{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

For more details on form error rendering, please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages).

---

**BTW** some minor optimisation on your code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def submit_interest_view(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    num_blogpost = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=user).count()
    if blog_post.author.email == user.email:
        return HttpResponse('You cannot submit interest to your own post.')
    interest_requests = Interest.objects.filter(interestsender=user, interestreceiver=blog_post.author, is_active=True)
    
    if interest_requests.exists():
        return HttpResponse('You have already submitted your interest to this post.')
    if request.method == 'POST':  # use request.method == 'POST' to submit POST request (like submitting a form)
        form = SubmitInterestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            author = Account.objects.get(email=user.email) # use 'author = user.account' if there is OneToOne relation between user and account
            obj.author = author
            obj.blog_post = blog_post
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your interests have been submitted', extra_tags='submittedinterest')
            context['success_message'] = "Updated"
            if request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("HomeFeed:main")):
                return redirect(reverse("HomeFeed:main"))
            elif request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("HomeFeed:detail", kwargs={'slug': slug })):        
                return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:detail', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
            else:   
                return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:main'))     
            #return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:detail', kwargs={'slug': slug})) # redirect to your post detail but use reverse to pass kwargs not just redirect
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Something went wrong. Please try again..', extra_tags='wronginterest')
            return render(request, "HomeFeed/submitinterest.html", {'form': form,'user': user, 'num_blogpost': num_blogpost, 'blog_post': blog_post}) 
    else:
        form = SubmitInterestForm()  #  if request.method isnt POST you still need to define your form so it can be displayed
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/submitinterest.html", {'form': form,'user': user, 'num_blogpost': num_blogpost, 'blog_post': blog_post}) # context dict
```

Comment: you need to set `obj.interstreceiver` value before saving the object. ie `object. interestreceiver=user`

Comment: Hi bro, @ruddra, so basically before my obj.save() statement, I will need to add one line of code `obj.interestsender=user`

Comment: should be sender and not receiver right? because I am the one sending the interest

Comment: and also do i need to include another `obj.interestreceiver=blog_post.author`?

Comment: Ruddra, also, why is it that after I submit the request to that particular post, I am unable to submit interest to other posts that belong to the same user. Because my intent is that you cannot submit interest again to the same post and not the same user. Actually i just started learning django not too long ago, if you have some time to spare, could you share how i can resolve this, and so advice on the code above as to whether it should be 'obj.interestsender=user' and not 'object. interestreceiver=user' and whether i also need 'obj.interestreceiver=blog_post.author' Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi @timago, sorry for delayed response. I think it is better if you ask a new question with more context and code regarding the problem. Thanks

Comment: no worries, thanks for replying me! I was so close to emailing you through your website but I saw your rules hahaha...anyways I have posted my question here. Hope that you can take a look. I believe it is because of what you mentioned that i need to add something before the obj(save) but I'm not sure what. Thank you! @ruddra https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594553/django-integrityerror-null-value-in-column-interestreceiver-id-of-relation-h/65595571?noredirect=1#comment115994745_65595571

Comment: hi ruddra, just in case you missed the message :) @ruddra